# Different .css applied within different pages on a website

Tags: css

i've been asked by a friend to help out with a website he's starting(e-shop). I am a total beginner so i just google everything :(. He does not have any access to the code(hosted by a provider), he can only edit the user.css file. The problem is, he wanted to remove border around the product pictures so i managed it by adding:

```
.product-grid .image img {
    border: 0px;
}
```

This worked fine for the product grid on the homepage("home"), however does not apply for the product grids within categories(picture "category"). It shows me that a different css is applied than mine user.css. Any idea. Just from the basics i've thought the user.css will overwrite any previous css that would refer to the same. Any idea how i can define the same for other pages as well?

[category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glKj8.jpg)

[Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMerh.jpg)

Comment: then just use `img{border-width: 0;}`

Comment: Don't do `img{border-width:0;}`. It will be aplied to all images.

Comment: I'm just here to express my astonishment that the username *beginner* was still available. And since I'm already here, I might as well leave some reading material for the beginner: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to overwrite any previous css use "Important"

```
.product-grid .image img {
border: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: thks francis, thats excatly what was necessary. worked like a charm :) thank you gus for the help

Comment: happy that my solution helped you